# Multiple entries, same postkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to structure my Firebase DB so all the user's exercises fall under the same postkey, since I am making a new push request for each exercise they currently aren't structured properly, as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZANp0.jpg

My Firebase code is:

```
function writeNewWorkout() { 
   // A post entry.
console.log(payload);

        var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        // Get a key for a new Post
        var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('Workout').push().key;
        // Write the new post's data
        var updates = {};
        updates[uid + '/Workout/' + newPostKey + "/" + exercise] = payload; // Add UID?

        return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

and the submit function to collect user entries (dynamic field entry):

```
$('.submitExercise').click(function () {
        var reps = [];
        $.each($('.repsClass'), function () {
            reps.push($(this).val());
        });
        if (reps.length == 0) {
            reps = "none";
        }

        var weight = [];
        $.each($('.weightClass'), function () {
            weight.push($(this).val());
        });
        if (weight.length == 0) {
            weight = "none";
        }

        exercise = document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value;
        alert(exercise);
        alert(reps);
        alert(weight);

        for (var i = 0; i <= reps.length - 1; i++)
        {
            payload["exercise"] = exercise,
                    payload["reps" + i] = reps[i],
                    payload["weight" + i] = weight[i];
        }
        writeNewWorkout();
    });
```

Could anyone advise my what change I should make?

I imagine I need a for loop in combination with an update method, Im just ot sure how to structure it.

EDIT:

I came up with the following, instead of using a postkey, I am using a date variable (since it is predictable), as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IBNb.jpg

Is this in acceptable solution?

The JSON Structure:

```
{
  "ZwYo0nB92oODcjjxJ0Eqeo4l3Ny1" : {
    "BodyStats" : {
      "-KbDFBzjRIVtaFWN325R" : {
        "arms" : "5",
        "bodyfat" : "2",
        "calves" : "3",
        "chest" : "4",
        "date" : "23/1/2017",
        "forearms" : "5",
        "neck" : "6",
        "shoulders" : "7",
        "thighs" : "8",
        "waist" : "9",
        "weight" : "10"
      },
      "-KbDHVZlyRHZnp7iwC80" : {
        "arms" : "5",
        "bodyfat" : "4",
        "calves" : "884",
        "chest" : "65",
        "date" : "22/1/2017",
        "forearms" : "56",
        "neck" : "5",
        "shoulders" : "14",
        "thighs" : "42",
        "waist" : "66",
        "weight" : "44"
      },
      "-KbDISlDA2c9HDvySxyY" : {
        "arms" : "",
        "bodyfat" : "",
        "calves" : "2",
        "chest" : "",
        "date" : "1/1/2017",
        "forearms" : "",
        "neck" : "",
        "shoulders" : "",
        "thighs" : "",
        "waist" : "",
        "weight" : ""
      }
    },
    "Journal" : {
      "-KbGSz7AqoRMId5S8pvV" : {
        "date" : "25/1/2017",
        "entry" : "",
        "title" : ""
      },
      "-KbGT3lFEMeg3TjeaQpY" : {
        "date" : "18/1/2017",
        "entry" : "",
        "title" : ""
      },
      "-KbGTBRO5FEwJXi3Ea0f" : {
        "date" : "13/1/2017",
        "entry" : "",
        "title" : ""
      },
      "-KbGTaLDpL6qrdNQn4am" : {
        "date" : "24/1/2017",
        "entry" : "Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. Hello this is a test. ",
        "title" : "Test"
      }
    },
    "Somatics" : {
      "-KbDEj4lyV1YeDIiiHxa" : {
        "comments" : "c",
        "date" : "23/1/2017",
        "energy" : "Mostly Energetic",
        "mood" : "Mostly Euphoric",
        "nutrition" : "Today was a good day, energetic, did a bunch, this is a test. Hellow how are you?",
        "sleep" : "Above Average"
      },
      "-KbDG2QT6R5fShe-y88_" : {
        "comments" : "",
        "date" : "24/1/2017",
        "energy" : "Slightly Energetic",
        "mood" : "Euphoric",
        "nutrition" : "",
        "sleep" : "Below Average"
      },
      "-KbDImS8hW_mg7PLNh4b" : {
        "comments" : "",
        "date" : "1/1/2017",
        "energy" : "Mostly Energetic",
        "mood" : "",
        "nutrition" : "",
        "sleep" : ""
      },
      "-KbDLP1owhsUzu2F_Vzj" : {
        "comments" : "",
        "date" : "25/1/2017",
        "energy" : "",
        "mood" : "Normal",
        "nutrition" : "",
        "sleep" : ""
      }
    },
    "Workout" : {
      "26-1-2017" : {
        "Bench Press" : {
          "exercise" : "Bench Press",
          "reps0" : "5",
          "weight0" : "185"
        }
      },
      "4-1-2017" : {
        "Bench Press" : {
          "exercise" : "Bench Press",
          "reps0" : "3",
          "weight0" : "3"
        },
        "Push Ups" : {
          "exercise" : "Push Ups",
          "reps0" : "3",
          "weight0" : "3"
        }
      },
      "6-1-2017" : {
        "Bench Press" : {
          "exercise" : "Bench Press",
          "reps0" : "",
          "reps1" : "",
          "reps2" : "",
          "reps3" : "",
          "reps4" : "",
          "reps5" : "",
          "reps6" : "",
          "weight0" : "",
          "weight1" : "",
          "weight2" : "",
          "weight3" : "",
          "weight4" : "",
          "weight5" : "",
          "weight6" : ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "exercises" : {
    "benchPress" : {
      "description" : "bench",
      "image" : "pic",
      "label" : "Bench Press",
      "name" : "Bench Press"
    },
    "pushUps" : {
      "description" : "pushups",
      "image" : "pic",
      "label" : "Push Ups",
      "name" : "Push Ups"
    },
    "sitUps" : {
      "description" : "situps",
      "image" : "pic",
      "label" : "Sit Ups",
      "name" : "Sit Ups"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included links to pictures of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, I should have known to do this. I updated the post as suggested, hopefully someone can help. Any overall DB structuring advice is appreciated.